# Fermat's Last Theorem's Proof

Tags: number-theory

Where can I find a copy of the proof that proves Fermat's Last Theorem? Also, what different mathematical topics would I need to know to fully understand all of the syntax and reasoning in the proof? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have a wonderful proof, but this comment doesn't allow enough characters to contain it.

Comment: The famed proof by Sir Andrew John Wiles requires some knowledge of Galois groups, homomorphisms, so I believe quite some knowledge of abstract algebra is needed.

Answer (score 17):

Here's a link the the paper:

Wiles, A. J. "[Modular elliptic curves and Fermat's Last Theorem](http://users.tpg.com.au/nanahcub/flt.pdf)", 
*Annals of Mathematics*, 141 (1995), 443-551.

It'll take most people several lifetimes of study to get close to understanding it all in perfect detail.

Comment: Is it free for download from the source?

Comment: @joejacobz You're welcome. Don't forget to show your appreciation with an up-vote ;o)

Comment: @Sigur Yes. Just follow the link.

Comment: I see and I have the paper. I'm asking if is possible to share it. No problems with Copyright?

Comment: @Sigur It was posted on Wikipedia as an article reference.

Comment: @joejacobz In addition to upvoting answers, you can *accept* (one answer per question) if you find it particularly helpful: simply click on the "greyed out" check-mark to the left of the helpful answer!

Comment: I always heard that the demonstration has more than 1000 pages ... ???

Comment: @Hexacoordinate-C: there are more than 80 bibliographical references. Each probably longer than 20 pages (not counting their own references). 1000 pages is certainly an understatement.

Answer (score 2):

You can find it here: **Andrew John Wiles.** *Modular elliptic curves and Fermat's Last Theorem*, Annals of Mathematics, **141** (1995), 443-552.

[image]